# Test if Google+ is already with my Website

Tags: google, google-search-console, links, google-plus

How can I verify or check if a website is already linked with Google plus?

I already added `<link href="https://plus.google.com/{+PageIdGoesHere}" rel="publisher" />` this to my head tag of my page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [this tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).

Enter your URL in the authorship testing result and check your status.
If your website is already linked to Google+, you will get "*Authorship is working for this webpage*".